# apt-get -d download to a specific directory

Tags: debian, apt-get

What are the options for `apt-get` on debian to download to a specific directory. Right now I'm using `apt-get -d install packagename` and then just fetch it in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` but it would be nice if I could actually redirect the package to some other directory. Normally in ubuntu I would just do `apt-get download` but this option isn't available for me in debian.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/apt-file.1.html. Check the link. Check the cache option.

Comment: `apt-get` gained the `download` command in Debian Wheezy which is not released yet (but is due to be released in the 1st quarter of May). Since Ubuntu builds on `testing` and `unstable` Debian archives its `apt-get` already has this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935836/720999) solves your problem.  That is, to fetch a package to the current directory you could do

```
apt-get -d -o dir::cache=`pwd` -o Debug::NoLocking=1 install package
```

One drawback which, *I think,* is still present is that it won't allow you to download a package which is already installed (even with `--force`) because this is the `install` command after all.  At least this is what happens with my `apt-get` `v0.8.10.3` from Debian Squeeze.

Comment: Can confirm that this won't download already-installed packages